# StripeInvalidRequestError: No such external account

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I want to create stripe payout to transfer fund from my account to the seller's account. If the seller doesn't have an stripe account I am trying to create a account using stripe.accounts.create and then I am creating an external account with stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount and connecting the sellers bank account to his stripe account. Now when I try to create a stripe payout the process is failing with this error.

My backend :

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27'
});

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { amount, recipientId, routingNumber, accountNumber,emailId } = req.body;
      
      let recipientAccountId;
      
      if (recipientId) {
        recipientAccountId = recipientId;
      } else {
        // Create a Custom account for the recipient
        const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
          type: 'custom',
          country: 'US',
          email: emailId,
          capabilities: {
            card_payments: {requested: true},
            transfers: {requested: true},
          },
        });

        recipientAccountId = account.id;
        console.log("customAccount",account)
        // Add the recipient's bank account details
      await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(recipientAccountId, {
          external_account: {
            object: 'bank_account',
            country: 'US', 
            currency: 'usd',
            routing_number: routingNumber,
            account_number: accountNumber
          }
        });
      }
    
     // Create a payout to the recipient's account
      const payout = await stripe.payouts.create({
        amount,
        currency: 'usd',
        method: 'standard',
        destination: recipientAccountId
      });

      // // //Create a session ID to pass back to the client
      const sessionId = payout.id;

      res.status(200).json({ sessionId });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while initiating the payout.' });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: No such external account: 'acct_1N2Aq7GfOcRyeiYj'
    at StripeError.generate (file:///C:/Users/gauth/OneDrive/Desktop/AAK/Blockchain-Dev/node_modules/stripe/esm/Error.js:7:20)
    at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (file:///C:/Users/gauth/OneDrive/Desktop/AAK/Blockchain-Dev/node_modules/stripe/esm/RequestSender.js:102:43)    
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'resource_missing',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
    message: "No such external account: 'acct_1N2Aq7GfOcRyeiYj'",
    param: 'destination',
    request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF?t=1682763438',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Sat, 29 Apr 2023 10:17:18 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '353',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',      
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'idempotency-key': '17e2ea5a-6362-4b3c-aabe-a7e6d2925b17',
      'original-request': 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF',
      'request-id': 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF',
      'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'resource_missing',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
  param: 'destination',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Sat, 29 Apr 2023 10:17:18 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '353',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',        
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'idempotency-key': '17e2ea5a-6362-4b3c-aabe-a7e6d2925b17',
    'original-request': 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF',
    'request-id': 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'  },
  requestId: 'req_qUBEETBOLIdSqF',
  statusCode: 400,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

I tried to console my **account** and I get the following . I want to know why **card_payments** and **transfers** are inactive

```
 {
  id: 'acct_1N2Aq7GfOcRyeiYj',
  object: 'account',
  business_profile: {
    mcc: null,
    name: null,
    product_description: null,
    support_address: null,
    support_email: null,
    support_phone: null,
    support_url: null,
    url: null
  },
  business_type: null,
  capabilities: { card_payments: 'inactive', transfers: 'inactive' },
  charges_enabled: false,
  country: 'US',
  created: 1682763436,
  default_currency: 'usd',
  details_submitted: false,
  email: 'gauthamvijay@rocketmail.com',
  external_accounts: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [],
    has_more: false,
    total_count: 0,
    url: '/v1/accounts/acct_1N2Aq7GfOcRyeiYj/external_accounts'
  },
  future_requirements: {
    alternatives: [],
    current_deadline: null,
    currently_due: [],
    disabled_reason: null,
    errors: [],
    eventually_due: [],
    past_due: [],
    pending_verification: []
  },
  metadata: {},
  payouts_enabled: false,
  requirements: {
    alternatives: [],
    current_deadline: null,
    currently_due: [
      'business_profile.mcc',
      'business_profile.url',
      'business_type',
      'external_account',
      'representative.first_name',
      'representative.last_name',
      'tos_acceptance.date',
      'tos_acceptance.ip'
    ],
    disabled_reason: 'requirements.past_due',
    errors: [],
    eventually_due: [
      'business_profile.mcc',
      'business_profile.url',
      'business_type',
      'external_account',
      'representative.first_name',
      'representative.last_name',
      'tos_acceptance.date',
      'tos_acceptance.ip'
    ],
    past_due: [
      'business_profile.mcc',
      'business_profile.url',
      'business_type',
      'external_account',
      'representative.first_name',
      'representative.last_name',
      'tos_acceptance.date',
      'tos_acceptance.ip'
    ],
    pending_verification: []
  },
  settings: {
    bacs_debit_payments: {},
    branding: {
      icon: null,
      logo: null,
      primary_color: null,
      secondary_color: null
    },
    card_issuing: { tos_acceptance: [Object] },
    card_payments: {
      decline_on: [Object],
      statement_descriptor_prefix: null,
      statement_descriptor_prefix_kana: null,
      statement_descriptor_prefix_kanji: null
    },
    dashboard: { display_name: null, timezone: 'Etc/UTC' },
    payments: {
      statement_descriptor: null,
      statement_descriptor_kana: null,
      statement_descriptor_kanji: null
    },
    payouts: {
      debit_negative_balances: false,
      schedule: [Object],
      statement_descriptor: null
    },
    sepa_debit_payments: {}
  },
  tos_acceptance: { date: null, ip: null, user_agent: null },
  type: 'custom'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A **Payout** represents money moving from your Stripe account's balance inside Stripe to your own bank account (or debit card) outside of Stripe.

This isn't what you want as you are trying to transfer funds to your seller's bank account. To do this, you first need to transfer funds into the seller's Stripe account's balance. To do this, you have to create a **Transfer** instead which represents money moving between one Stripe account's balance inside Stripe to another Stripe account's balance still inside Stripe.

Once you have transferred funds from your platform's balance to the seller's account balance, you will then be able to create a Payout to send funds from their balance to their bank account outside of Stripe.

Now, there is a lot more to this than just creating a Transfer. To accept payments on behalf of a third-party seller, you have to collect detailed information about that seller before they can receive funds such as their address or date of birth. You also have to have them accept Stripe's terms of services.

It's crucial that you take the time to read the detailed information that Stripe covers in their documentation about Custom accounts [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts). It's highly likely that you want to choose a different approach such as using Express accounts and Stripe's own onboarding path. This is unfortunately way beyond what can be explained in a StackOverflow answer. I'd recommend carefully reviewing their docs first and then contacting their support team otherwise [here](https://support.stripe.com/contact)